TS React is not interpreting function extended type attr as a React Function (not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes)
Could someone explain why React is not interpreting a function that handles the component declaration as an extendable type attribute as a React React Function, resulting in the error: Type '[...]' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes[...]', but when I declare it directly in the parameter it's interpreted as a React Function element:
type RenderComponentOptions<P> = {
  Component: React.ComponentType<P>,
  props: P
}

function directlyOnParameterDeclaration<Props extends {}>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Props>, props: Props
) {
  return <Component {...props} />
}

function extandableFunctionAttributeDeclaration<
  Props extends {},
  T extends React.ComponentType<Props>
>(Component: T, props: Props) {
  return <Component {...props} />
}

At the Component usage (<Component {...props} /> at line 16) on the extandableFunctionAttributeDeclaration function will result in this TS error:
Type 'Props' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<T, Props>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<T, Props>'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<T, Props>'.
      Type 'Props' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<T, Props>'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<T, Props>'. (2322)


You cannot assume Props P extends {} if you are going to use React.ComponentType. Try this
function extandableFunctionAttributeDeclaration<
  T extends React.ComponentType,
  Props extends JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes<T, object>,
>(Component: T, props: Props) {
  return <Component {...props} />;
}

There is a lot of internal infer happening if you refer the react types (node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts)
 type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
            ? T extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer U> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer U>
                ? ReactManagedAttributes<U, P>
                : ReactManagedAttributes<T, P>
            : ReactManagedAttributes<C, P>;

I would suggest to stick with RenderComponentOptions type wherever possible.
